# WPF Observable collection, dynamic type

Tags: wpf, dynamic, binding, devexpress, observablecollection

I need to ability to bind a grid to a collection of variale type (Interface/Type T/dynamic etc)

I thought that I would be able to bind the collection to an interface and then change the object exteded off of this interface and the UI would update accordingly.

```
private readonly ObservableCollection<IExportItemModel> _exportedDataCollection = new ObservableCollection<IExportItemModel>();
    public ObservableCollection<IExportItemModel> ExportedDataCollection
    {
        get
        {
            return _exportedDataCollection;
        }
    }
```

.

```
List<spGetDataByTransactionId_Result> t = _repository.GetDataByTransactionId(new Guid());
List<IExportItemModel> tempList = new List<IExportItemModel>();
t.ForEach(r=>tempList.Add(new FixedWidthModel(r)));

ExportedDataCollection.AddRange(tempList);
```

But the UI doesn't reflect the changes, or at least DevExpress doesn't.

Would there be a better way that I am not thinking about?

Thanks in advance,
Oli

Comment: what do you mean the UP doesn't reflect the changes ? what do you expect to see? what are you seeing ?

Comment: Is it the collection that doesn't update? Or is it your models content? It's hard to tell without knowing what IExportItemModel is, could you post it? Remember that if binding to items in the list, you will need to have IExportItemModel inherit INotifyPropertyChanged, for signalling the gui that a redraw is required. Give us some more info, and I'm sure we can help you =)

Comment: @Stian IExportItemModel is an empty Interface, it has nothing it it. I made it purely for having an interface to extent and a type to bind the collection.

Comment: @Noctis The UI does nothing, doesn't even show the type but I assume that DevExpress is masking this.

Comment: @Oli I cannot  answer your question, without more info, like your xaml. So I see what you trying to do here. What does your debugoutbut say? Any binding errors exceptions etc?

Comment: an [ObservableCollection<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx) does not have `AddRange` method as used in `ExportedDataCollection.AddRange(tempList);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of way to achieve what you want, depending on your chosen UI control. For example, if you had an `ObservableCollection<SomeInterface>` collection containing a number of different classes that have implemented that interface, then you could display them all in a collection control.

However, if you chose to use a `DataGrid` with `AutoGenerateColumns="True"`, then you would only see the properties that were actually defined in the interface and no extra ones defined in the classes. On the other hand, if you data bound that collection to an `ItemsControl.ItemsSource`, then you *could* data bind to *all* of the properties, even those defined within the implementing classes.

You'll find similar results using base classes. To avoid *all* problems though, it is often easiest to use an `ObservableCollection<object>` collection.

Comment: Oh, an object, why have I not tried that.  I'll give it a go after my current task.

Comment: Yes setting it as a plain object worked perfectly for now thanks.